# How to calculate APY interest rate from Normal interest rate

Tags: calculation, interest-rate

In one of the site I saw for 1% interest rate daily compounded interest the APY interest rate is 1.005003 ! How is this calculated I google a lot and didnt find how it is calculated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When speaking interest rates it is usually expressed in “per year”. However the method of compounding makes the actual interest rate a bit different.

Usually you will divide the interest rate with number of periods. In your case you get

```
1% / 365 = 0.00274% daily
```

This means that your annual actual interest rate will become

```
(1 + 0.00274%)^365 - 1 = 1.005%
```